# .blur() sound notifications

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two text boxes whose values are 'yes' and 'no'. When I type 'yes' in the first text box, it beeps and the same should happen with the remaining text box. The sound should play **only once** when I enter the correct value in the corresponding text boxes.

In my case, the sound is repeating again and again... I don't know what might be the cause.

```
<input type="text" id="question"/>
<input type="text" id="question1"/> 
<audio src="beep.mp3" id="mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

function checkResults() {

    if ($('#question').val().toLowerCase() == 'yes') {
            document.getElementById("mp3").play();

    }

    if ($('#question1').val().toLowerCase() == 'no') {
        document.getElementById("mp3").play();
    }


}

$('input').blur(checkResults);
```

Comment: you mean :`.pause()` when `.val()` is `no`.

Comment: i.e., play the beep only once if the value i entered in the text box is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound is playing more than once because you're checking the `blur` event, so every time the user blurs out of the box the sound will replay as long as the correct answer in in the box. Instead you should check for `keyup` event.

Example:

```
var answers = {
    'question': 'yes',
    'question1': 'no'
};

function checkResults() {
    var $this = $(this), val = $this.val().toLowerCase();

    for (var k in answers) {
        if (answers.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            if (answers[$this.attr('id')] && answers[$this.attr('id')] === val) {
                  play(); 
            }
        }
    }   
}

function play() {
    var sound = document.getElementById('mp3');
    sound.pause();
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.play();
}

$('input').on('keyup', checkResults);
```

JSFiddle demo

**http://jsfiddle.net/7ahpgt5s/**

Comment: Moogs, Thanq For a good answer, but is it possible to add +1 score for every correct answer. I tried it but my score is getting as 2 for correct answer and for next answer the score is going back to 0. Any Ideas... Here is the my fiddle about score...http://jsfiddle.net/7ahpgt5s/2/

Comment: Hi Moogs,checked fiddle,its fine except 2 small issue.(1).. As i said +1 score for every correct answer, but in ur fiddle i've written yes and no for two text boxes and score gone to 2. now  u put the cursor in text-box-1 and use TAB Key, so that it goes to Text-box-2, the score is increasing and if u do the same as i said above score is increasing like(3,4,......). I dont want this to happen. the final score should be 2, since there are only two questions. (2)...it seems the fiddle is not working on ios/android devices beacuse of 'keyup' as the music is repeating for every character i press.

Comment: Hey Moogs, sorry if i'm disturbing u with my questions.